# jquery on success to process data returned from the server

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I am sending a jquery $.ajax(); request to the server, and want my onsuccess function to work according to the params i **sent to the server** rather than the params i **received from the server** 
because each time my site is supposed to behave depending on what i sent, rather than what i received
how do i attach my "sent" parameters, without making them global to my onsuccess function ?

this is my function :

```
 $.ajax({
            url : this.soapTarget,
            type : "POST",
            dataType : "xml",
            data : this.soapMSG,
            processData : false,
            beforeSend : function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPTarget",this.soapTarget);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction",this.soapAction);
            },
            contentType : "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
            success : OnSuccess,
            error : OnError
            });
```

when this function is actually a parameter in a more global function , this is why it has "this.soapMSG" and this.soapTarget and this.soapAction as its parameters

in my OnSuccess function i want to use the "this" object to display the result on the web page

how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var self=this;
$.ajax({
    url : this.soapTarget,
    type : "POST",
    dataType : "xml",
    data : this.soapMSG,
    processData : false,
    beforeSend : function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPTarget",this.soapTarget);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction",this.soapAction);
    },
    contentType : "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    success : function(){
        $(self).html('your data goes here'); // self points to this object now
    },
    error : OnError
 });
```

Comment: "this" is not an html element, it is a soap request
i want my onsuccess function to act according to the soapAction value -> but it is not returned to me

Comment: i want to the onsuccess callback pass the "this" parameter

Answer (score 0):

need to wrap onsuccess with your own function like this:

```
succes: function(response, status,xhr){
OnSuccess(response,status,xhr,moreparams);
}
```